# Is it ok to use dices to generate seed for trezor on coldcard?

Tags: wallet, seed, hardware-wallet

Coldcard's derive entropy function doe snot have dice method. The only way to generate a seed using dices on coldcard is on "import seed".

Is it ok if I use this feature and generate a new seed with dices and then put this seed on Trezor?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to generate seed words that are BIP39 compliant.

It is clear to me that you wish to use dice in order to create seed entropy.  Yes, you can use Coldcard to convert your die rolls into seed words.  Those seed words can be imported into any BIP39-compliant wallet software, including hardware wallets like Trezor.

Alternately, you can use other methods to create seed words from dice.  The top method that comes to mind is the Ian Coleman BIP39 generator.  Check the option to show entropy details, and you will have a spot to enter your dice rolls.  You can select 12-24 words for your output, in three-word increments.